# Installing Windows Identity Foundation on Azure Web Site Via Git

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, wif

I'm hosting a MVC 4 web site on Azure.  The site requires Windows Identity Foundation to authenticate a web service call.  I'm getting this error:

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

I've done some reading and it seams you can install via a web role.  However, I'm deploying my site via Git and don't have any Azure web roles in my project.

Is there any other way to install WIF on the hosted cloud server?

Comment: You store compiled dll in Git? Even with a web role install you must manually set 'copy local = true' for a some dll's like 'Microsoft.IdentityModel'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring the GAC dll. 
Try using the IdentityModel NuGet package instead.

https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel/

Comment: Great and easy answer. Thank you